# Spring MVC, injection of Hibernate Service into Spring bean is failing, not sure why

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a spring bean that I have configured in applicationContext like below:

```
<bean id="beanIRPlus" class="org.jadefalcon.demo.server.Spring.beans.BeanIRPlus" />
```

Then I have a Hibernate Service like below that I am trying to inject into the Spring bean. Normally, for example, if I use a prototype bean thats injected into my controller and that has an injected Hibernate service it works fine, however for this particular bean it is a singleton so its created when the application starts up. I made sure to even put the bean declaration at the very end of the `applicationContext.xml` file figuring maybe it has to be put after anything Hibernate related but the issue is still persisting. Its giving a null pointer exception, that the `CasesService` object doesn't exist. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong is greatly appreciated:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.jadefalcon.demo.domain.Cases;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service("casesservice")
@Transactional
public class CasesService {

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("service");

    @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void add(Cases cases) {
        logger.debug("Saving new search");

        // Retrieve session from Hibernate
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        // Save
        session.save(cases);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the configuration file (applicationContext.xml) as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see how you are trying to inject it. You have at least two options:

- xml. Define a `<property name=".." ref="casesservice">` in your controller bean definition
- annotations. Use `@Autowired private CaseService service` (or `@Inject`)

Comment: sorry for not including that, I am using @Autowired, its just a plain injection this way that I've used tons of times before, I am trying to inject (the Hibernate service object) as being null based off the set of circumstances I described above (it being a singleton bean instantiated at app start)

Comment: if you are using @Autowired, do you have `<context:component-scan>` in your context xml? This is very hard to diagnose without the configuration - just post it.

Comment: Since you are using @Autowired, does your BeanIRPlus class have @Component (or @Service)?